# camel-component for ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Please excuse, if this is a stupid question. The hole camel-stuff is new to me, so I really have no 'global view'.
I like to use a queuing in my camel-installation. I fount ActiveMQ to be one solution and then stumbled over two different components (or there uri):
[ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) and [JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html).

As ActiveMQ is implementing JMS 1.1, what is the difference between using both URI? Or in other words: Can I use both and if yes, which one should be using in which cases?

Comment: Thx for the answers! So I have to start with JMS and use constants as far as possible so that I can switch if the decision has been made for ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1):

The `activemq` uri represents a JMS Camel Component built specifically for the ActiveMQ message broker, while the `jms` uri works with any JMS compliant message broker.  The ActiveMQ component does all of the things that the JMS component does, but it requires less configuration because much of that work has been done for you by the implementation.

If you are planning on using ActiveMQ as your JMS broker then I would suggest using the ActiveMQ component.  If you are possibly going to use another broker in the future then go ahead and configure a standard JMS component.

Answer (score 1):

With the camel-ActiveMQ component you will be able to use some nice configuration features that come with the AactiveMQ library. For example, the PooledConnectionFactory.